# JButton image with different paths

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have added an icon to my `JButton` and the image is taken from a specific path inside my project files. But the problem is on another machine the path may be slightly different.

For instance my entire image path is `home/jon/hello/folder/image.png`, but on another machine the path may be `/project/folder/william/hello/folder/image.png`. Meaning the starting part of the path is different but from the hello part would be the same.

How can I make my path in my button code to be able to match the difference? My button code is below :

```
    btn = new JButton(BUTTON_COLLAPSE_NESTED().toString());
    btn.setIcon(newImageIcon("home/jon/hello/folder/image.png"));
    btn.setActionCommand(BUTTON_COLLAPSE_NESTED().toString());
    btn.addActionListener(btnListener);
    btnPnl.add(btn);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is why you shouldn't use absolute paths. Place the image in the jar, and use relative paths to resources, with the path based on the classpath to your class files.

For instance, if `image.png` is located in an images folder just off of the class file folder, you'd do something like:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/images/image.png");
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
```

or something similar.

Comment: I actually have an existing image folder already, its a default for the project I am working on. The location is not in the jar and I need to use this folder for image storing. The path is, hello/folder/image.png. Would this still work ?

Comment: Its just to add an icon to the JButton

Comment: I need it to work without moving the images location

Comment: Whether you put it in the jar or not, is it going to be packaged with your app or not? If not, why make your app dependent on some end user's file system?

Comment: @johnmars: you'll need to use some type of set up file or Properties file so that the program will know where to look. Either that or load the file location into the command line args.

Comment: Yes, it is going to be packaged with the app

Comment: I am trying to change it so that it is not dependent on a end users file system, and this is where I am stuck

Comment: then follow my first advice!